# Json common key make group in symfony

Tags: php, json

I have a json. My json have common keys. I want to show common keys in one json. Now my json like this :

```
 {
 data: [
    {
     updatedDate: null,
     active: true,
     id: 80,
     lessonName: "HZİ 413 Language in Use",
     educationDegree: "Lisans",
     academicYear: "2013-2014",
     language: "İngilizce",
     lessonHour: 4,
     addedDate: "2014-02-21T19:54:23+0000"
    },
    {
    updatedDate: null,
    active: true,
    id: 81,
    lessonName: "HZİ 411 English in Context I",
    educationDegree: "Lisans",
    academicYear: "2013-2014",
    language: "İngilizce",
    lessonHour: 8,
    addedDate: "2014-02-21T19:53:47+0000"
    },
    {
    updatedDate: null,
    active: true,
    id: 82,
    lessonName: "HZİ 512 English in Context II ",
    educationDegree: "Lisans",
    academicYear: "2014-2015",
    language: "İngilizce",
    lessonHour: 12,
    addedDate: "2014-02-21T19:52:44+0000"
    }
 ]
}
```

I want to collect below in academicYear key, if academicKeys are equal.
I hope so I could explain my problem.

My code here :

```
    public function indexAction()
{
    $data = $this->get('service.lesson')->get();

    $data=json_decode($data,true);

    $out = [];

    foreach($data as $element) {
        $out[$element['academicYear']][] =
            [
            'lessonName'      => $element['lessonName'],
            'lessonHour'      => $element['lessonHour'],
            'educationDegree' => $element['educationDegree'],
        ];
    }

    var_dump(json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

    return $this->createApiResponse(compact('data'));
}
```

When I tried var_dump($data);

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\Lesson)[1637]
  private 'id' => int 80
  private 'lessonName' => string 'HZİ 413 Language in Use' (length=24)
  private 'educationDegree' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter)[1654]
      public '__initializer__' => 
        object(Closure)[1646]
          ...
      public '__cloner__' => 
        object(Closure)[1647]
          ...
      public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
      private 'id' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => int 127
      private 'yoksisId' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => null
      private 'name' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => null
      private 'parameterType' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => null
  private 'academicYear' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter)[1653]
      public '__initializer__' => 
        object(Closure)[1646]
          ...
      public '__cloner__' => 
        object(Closure)[1647]
          ...
      public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
      private 'id' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => int 509
      private 'yoksisId' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => null
      private 'name' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => null
      private 'parameterType' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YokParameter) => null
  private 'language' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\Language)[1665]
      public '__initializer__' => 
        object(Closure)[1657]
          ...
      public '__cloner__' => 
        object(Closure)[1658]
          ...
      public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
      private 'id' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\Language) => int 83
      private 'name' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\Language) => null
      private 'yoksisId' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\Language) => null
      private 'code' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\Language) => null
  private 'lessonHour' => int 4
  private 'addedDate' => 
    object(DateTime)[1632]
      public 'date' => string '2014-02-21 19:54:23.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  private 'user' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YoksisEntity) => 
    object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[1286]
      private 'id' => int 30
      private 'tcId' => string '********' (length=11)
      private 'email' => string '******' (length=7)
      private 'firstName' => string '*****' (length=5)
      private 'lastName' => string '*****' (length=7)
      private 'roles' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1309]
          ...
      private 'phone' => null
      private 'mobile' => null
      private 'userType' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\UserType)[1319]
          ...
      private 'personnelTitle' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\PersonnelTitle)[1329]
          ...
      private 'assignmentTitle' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\AssignmentTitle)[1339]
          ...
      private 'administrativeTitles' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1358]
          ...
      private 'personnelDepartment' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Department)[1368]
          ...
      private 'assignmentDepartmentGroups' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1384]
          ...
      private 'phoneBookDepartments' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1385]
          ...
      private 'menus' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1414]
          ...
      private 'notifications' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1439]
          ...
      protected 'createdAt' => 
        object(DateTime)[1282]
          ...
      protected 'updatedAt' => 
        object(DateTime)[1283]
          ...
      protected 'deletedAt' => null
  private 'yoksisId' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YoksisEntity) => int 423309
  private 'updatedDate' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YoksisEntity) => null
  private 'active' (AppBundle\Entity\Yoksis\YoksisEntity) => boolean true
  protected 'createdAt' => 
    object(DateTime)[1633]
      public 'date' => string '2016-08-25 06:27:46.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  protected 'updatedAt' => 
    object(DateTime)[1634]
      public 'date' => string '2016-08-25 06:27:46.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  protected 'deletedAt' => null
```

Comment: I think this is a framework independent problem. What php have you tried?

Comment: my php version is php7.0.

Comment: Sorry I meant what php code have you tried?

Comment: I added at my question.

Comment: @Yoshi your demo is working. $data = $this->get('service.lesson')->get(); my json it is. I dont write with hand. I retrieve data.

Comment: I understand, though without seeing what the actual data is that you're working with, I can't answer your question.

Comment: @Yoshi. real data in your demo :D just I retrieve from database. I guess I can't decode json in symfony. I meant json_decode($data,true) doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, you can decode json just fine, symfony will not interfere here. Though you need to be sure the input (before decoding) is what you think it is. Seems you encode something that issn't just plain data. You could add `var_dump($data);` after `$data = $this->get('service.lesson')->get();` and add that output to your question. Maybe that will clear things a bit.

Comment: @Yoshi, I added response of var_dump($data) in question.

Comment: @Kerim I undeleted my answer and added a comment regarding the *group value*. What you need to do is to find how you can retrieve the relevant value from each lesson. Also it seems you don't need to `json_decode` anything, looks much like `$this->get('service.lesson')->get();` already returns an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a simple *group by* functionality, this could be abstracted to be reusable, though if needed only in this specific instance, here's an example of how you could do it:

```
$groups = [];

foreach ($input as $element) {
    $groupValue = $element['academicYear'];

    # or in your case, something like:
    # $groupValue = $element->getAcademicYear()->getName();

    if (!array_key_exists($groupValue, $groups)) {
        $groups[$groupValue] = [];
    }

    $groups[$groupValue][] = $element;
}

print_r($groups);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/kqsQl

Comment: statusCode: 500,
message: "Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\Lesson as array"

Comment: From your question, your input data is a plain array, no objects or anything. You probably need to showcase the real input data.

Comment: I edited as $data. But I have this error already. My $data return json value. But I want to this json reformatted below academicYear.

Comment: Thank you so much for help.